# HTML Help indenting first line in <dd>

Tags: html, css, chm, html-help, html-help-workshop

I'm creating an HTML Help file (yeah, yeah, I know it's old fashioned but Microsoft has yet to provide a newer replacement).

When I open the file in a normal browser, the text appears how I expect. But when I open the file in the HTML help viewer, the first line within each `<dd>` element is indented, which I don't want.

[image]

Here's my CSS file.

```
body 
{
  color: #111;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}
dt {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
dd {
  margin-left: 18px;
}
pre {
  color: blue;
}
```

And here's part of my HTML.

```
<!doctype html public "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=Windows-1252">
<title>CYGNUSSTATEINFO Structure</title>
<link href="Style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<h1>CYGNUSSTATEINFO Structure</h1>

<p>
The CYGNUSSTATEINFO structure contains information about the current state and settings of the Cygnus application. This information may be useful for programming extensions that need more information about the data being processed. This structure contains the following members.
</p>

<dt>HWND hCygnusWnd</dt>
<dd>
A handle to the main Cygnus window.
</dd>

<dt>LPWSTR lpszCurrFile</dt>
<dd>
A Unicode string that specifies the name of the current file being edited. Note that this member is for display purposes only and does not contain a fully qualified path.
</dd>

<dt>int nStartOffset</dt>
<dd>
Specifies the offset of the start of any selection. This may be useful when it is necessary to know the offset of the data being processed. This member is zero if there is no selection associated with the current task.
</dd>

<dt>int nBytesPerRow</dt>
<dd>
Specifies the current number of bytes per row.
</dd>

<dt>int nOffsetRadix</dt>
<dd>
Specifies the current offset radix. This is the notation used to show the offset of each row. It will be 16 for hexadecimal, 10 for decimal.
</dd>

<dt>int nGroupBy</dt>
<dd>
Specifies the number of bytes per group in the hex portion of the display. This value is one if there is no byte grouping.
</dd>

<!-- Etc.... -->

</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone understand why the first line is being indented here? I've tried setting `text-indent: 0` with no success. I also tried changing the DOCTYPE to `<!doctype html>`, but nothing changes this.

Comment: Who the hell downvotes a question without saying why? Just because you don't have the answer, that doesn't make the question bad!

Comment: I seem to recall having a similar issue to this **many** years ago. I think I abandoned `dl` because I couldn't get the help viewer to style them as I wanted.

Comment: Does help viewer recognize the `:first-line` pseudo selector?

Comment: @disinfor: Surprisingly, setting no indent for `dd::first-line` does not work either. I can only assume the HTML Help browser is funky, although I would've guessed it would be using components from Edge or IE to keep the rendering engine more current. (Just tried viewing my HTML file with Internet Explorer and it does not indent.)

Comment: @JonP: Yeah, originally I used `<p>` tags with a CSS class. But that requires **much** more typing.

Comment: Completely irrelevant side note.... your ADO Helper from way back in 2011 is pretty timeless!

Comment: @JonP: Heh, that was a while ago. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following statement to the `<head>` section of all your HTML files.
This works if the HTML topic files are encapsulated in a .chm help file.

```html
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE11"/>
```

e.g.:

```html
<!doctype html public "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=Windows-1252">
<title>CYGNUSSTATEINFO Structure</title>
<link href="Style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE11"/> 
</head>
```

[image]

For further information have a look at our FAR HTML knownledge base [CSS3 in FAR Browser](http://kb.helpwaregroup.com/far/css3)

and Rick Strahl's Web log [Make your CHM Help Files show HTML5 and CSS3 Content](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/feb/15/make-your-chm-help-files-show-html5-and-css3-content)

Comment: Yes indeed, that was the issue. Looks like HTMLHelp's default settings tell it to completely ignore some CSS settings. Who would have thought?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `text-indent:0;` to the CSS rule for `dd`, and maybe also try to add `!important` if it doesn't work as is.

If that doesn't work, it might be due to specifity (a more complex selector overriding it).

You could also

1. Try to use inline styles in the HTML, like `<dd style="text-indent: 0;"> A handle` ...
2. Try to use a more specific CSS selector in your stylesheet, like `body dt dd {...}`

By the way: I just saw that - at least in your example code above - you don't have a `body` tag...

Comment: Thanks, but I mentioned that I did try this. I also just added `!Important` as you suggested, but that doesn't seem to do anything for some reason.

Comment: please note the additions to my original answer

Comment: Surprisingly, even this does not work. As mentioned, this is not even an issue in a regular browser. The HTML Help viewer appears to be doing something very strange here.

Comment: how about the missing body tag?

Comment: I added `text-indent: 0 !important` to the body section of my CSS file. I also added the missing `<body>` tag (thanks for that!). But still no luck.